# mysql .ibd file deleted. I want to DB data recovery

Tags: mysql

Because of my computer system error, Some MySql .ibd file deleted in MySql data folder. And there is only the .frm file left.
So, **Tablespace is missing for table 'reservation'.'question'.** error has occurred.

reservation is database. question is table.

I tested the following method to restore data.

First method:

1.Take a backup of .frm file.

2.Create the table using the SQL queries.

3.The following command was executed.

```
SELECT * FROM reservation.answer2;
ALTER TABLE reservation.answer2 DISCARD TABLESPACE;
ALTER TABLE reservation.answer2 IMPORT TABLESPACE;
```

The result of this method was not data recovery.

Second Method

1.I have added a property to my.ini

```
 [mysqld]
 innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

2.And the following command was executed.

```
mysqldump -u root -p --lock-all-tables reservation.question > c:\dump20171009.sql;
```

'--lock-all-tables' for adding this is due to **'when using LOCK TABLES
Operation failed with exitcode 2'** error.

This command occurred this error.

> mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table `question`': Tablespace
>   is missin g for table `reservation`.`question`. (1812)

Aren't there any alternatives?

Is data recovery impossible without .ibd file?
I want to data recovery in 'reservation.question'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.frm` file only contains data on the structure of the table, not its contents. The `.ibd` file holds the contents of the table -- if it was deleted, your data is gone.